# handler.sendMessage() is not reaching the handleMessage() in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity, thread-safety

I have created the handler,

```
    public final Handler handlerPositionTest = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
         Log.i(TAG, "handleMessage------------reached");
          //MyCode here
        }
    };
```

Also I have a generic event listener to receive the event details,

```
private GenericEventListener PositionStatusChangedListener = new GenericEventListener() {
            public void eventTriggered(Object sender, Event event) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Event triggered here------------");
            Log.i(TAG, "Event is not null------------:"+event);
            Log.i(TAG, "hanlder------------:"+handlerPositionTest);
            Message msg = handlerPositionTest.obtainMessage();
            msg.what = 2;
            msg.obj = e;
            handlerPositionTest.sendMessage(msg);
}
};
```

If i trigger the event continuously the **sendMessage()** method is not reach the **handleMessage()** method in the handler for few seconds.And it lost that event message as well.If I tried after few seconds it works correctly,I mean it's reaching the **handleMessage()**.

I am not clear about the scenario to reproduce this issue.It occurs randomly.

if you guys have any idea about this issue please leave the comment.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not see any code to initiate the handler to another thread. Are you doing heavy work on the UI thread?

Comment: yes,I know it may leads to heavy work. but is there any relation with my current stuff?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do start the handler on a background thread if you are doing synchronous calls that don't return in a timely manner.

```
    HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread(
            "Background thread",
            android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND
    );
    handlerThread.start();
    mHandler = new android.os.Handler(handlerThread.getLooper(), this);
```

Just make sure to put all updates of the UI within a `runOnUiThread(Runnable)`

For more information about threads and processes I recommend you to check out the [Android developer guide to processes and threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

Comment: @math...I am completely new to this concept.Shall I try to implement your code with the eventTriggered() method?